# How to output value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am a complete beginner in PHP. However I know how to output the value of custom field. I am having a bit of problems with arrays. The post meta key is `fw_options`. The value has multiple arrays and looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'featured_post' => false,
    'featured_expiry' => '',
    '_featured_book_string' => '0',
    'reading_level' => 'medium',
    'reading_type' => 
    array (
      'time' => 'fixed',
      'hourly' => 
      array (
        'hourly_read' => '',
        'estimated_hours' => '',
      ),
      'fixed' => 
      array (
        'reading_times' => '500',
      ),
    ),
    'reading_duration' => 'one_month',
    'english_level' => 'fluent',
    'readers_level' => 'starter',
    'expiry_date' => '2019/12/31',
    'show_attachments' => 'off',
    'read_documents' => 
    array (
    ),
    'address' => '',
    'longitude' => '',
    'latitude' => '',
    'country' => 
    array (
      0 => '717',
    ),
  ),
)
```

I have this code which I have tried with no success:

```
$array = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fw_options', true );
echo $array[0]['reading_type']['fixed']['reading_times'];
```

How can I output the value `500` from the post meta key `reading_times`?

Comment: So, this is `0` index of a great array and you need to get `reading_times` value for each row? And resultant array should looks like `array(500,200,404,...);`?

Comment: what is the output or error when you tried this?

Comment: Use var_dump($array) to get more info about the result, then use it to update the question

Comment: @AksenP reading_times has the value 500 only. That's the output I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Print array according to key 
First hold the value into a variable than print according to array key

```
$data = array(
            'featured_post' => false,
            'featured_expiry' => '',
            '_featured_book_string' => '0',
            'reading_level' => 'medium',
            'reading_type' =>
                array(
                    'time' => 'fixed',
                    'hourly' =>
                        array(
                            'hourly_read' => '',
                            'estimated_hours' => '',
                        ),
                    'fixed' =>
                        array(
                            'reading_times' => '500',
                        ),
                ),
            'reading_duration' => 'one_month',
            'english_level' => 'fluent',
            'readers_level' => 'starter',
            'expiry_date' => '2019/12/31',
            'show_attachments' => 'off',
            'read_documents' =>array(),
            'address' => '',
            'longitude' => '',
            'latitude' => '',
            'country' =>
                array(
                    0 => '717',
                ),
        );

echo $data['reading_type']['fixed']['reading_times'];
```

Output #**500**

Comment: Great !
 please make it correct so its help others as well !